# Limit of the continuous function

Tags: limits, functions, continuity

Simplify the subsequent function:

$f(x)=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{ln(e^n+x^n)}{n}$

and $n>0, x>0$

Already known: The function is continuous in $\mathbb{R}$. And when $x\leq e$, the function is 1. I want to know the form of the function when $x \ge e$. From the book, the final form of f(x) when $x>e$ will be $f(x)=ln(x), x>e$

Question: How to simplify the expression and get $f(x)$?

Thank you very much!

Comment: $f(x) \geq \lim \frac {e^{n}} n=\infty$ for all $x >0$.

Comment: There must be something wrong in what you wrote, as Kavi Rama Murthy says the limit diverges for all $x > 0$. So it can't be continuous on $\Bbb R$ and it certainly can't be 1 anywhere at all.

Comment: Thank you Giano. I miss a 'ln' in the function. I have to modify the post.

Comment: Thank you Murthy for your comment! I have made a mistake in the function I hope it does not bother you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much thought, the *mathematician's favorite trick* will be used to start things off:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{\ln(e^n +x^n)\over n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{\ln(e^n +x^n)-\ln(x^n)+\ln(x^n)\over n}$$

Using the quotient and power rules for logarithms gives

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{\ln({e^n +x^n \over x^n})+n\ln(x)\over n}=\ln x+\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{\ln(({e\over x})^n + 1)\over n}$$

It now suffices to show that the limit in the last term is 0, but this is obvious, since the numerator approaches $\ln(1)=0$ in the limit, and the denominator approaches $\infty$.

Comment: Thanks Andrew for your help! However, the f(x) seems incorrect after using the L'Hosiptal's Rule. With this method, it seems the limit tends to ln(x) when n tends to infinty, which is also the answer from the book. I wonder if there is a way to get the same result without using the rule because the exercise is presented before the rule content. Thank you again!

Comment: I graphed the two on [desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vhkggogbim) and it does seem to match, so perhaps there is a mistake somewhere in my work, I will look into it and try again.

Comment: Okay, I know see the trick they want you to use: try adding and subtracting $\ln(x^n)$ in the numerator, and you'll see that the negative term can be combined with the natural log term and you'll get ${{\ln(({e\over x})^n+1)}\over n} +\ln x$. It now suffices to show that the first term approaches 0 in the limit, which is kind of obvious, since the numerator approaches 0 in the limit, but the denominator goes to $\infty$.

Comment: Okay, I just completely changed my answer accordingly!

Comment: Thanks Andrew! You are perfectly correct!

Answer (score 0):

Using L'hospital law, this is of the form of $\lim \frac{\infty}{\infty}$ and can be written as $$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\frac {(e^n+\ln x\cdot x^n)}1$$which is divergent.

Comment: L'Hospital's theorem applies to differentiable function, and here we deal with a sequence (which depends on $n \in \mathbb N$); one cannot differentiate with respect to integer variables. There is an analogue for sequence of L'Hospital's theorem, though, and it is called the [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem). This is what you want to use.

Comment: Thanks user1058602 and Alex! I really appreciate your help. However, I've made a mistake in the original post which loses a "ln". And I have already modified the question.